# pass JSON to HTTP POST Request

Tags: json, node.js, curl, express, node-request

I'm trying to make a HTTP POST request to the google QPX Express API [1] using ***nodejs*** and ***request*** [2].

My code looks as follows:

```
    // create http request client to consume the QPX API
    var request = require("request")

    // JSON to be passed to the QPX Express API
    var requestData = {
        "request": {
            "slice": [
                {
                    "origin": "ZRH",
                    "destination": "DUS",
                    "date": "2014-12-02"
                }
            ],
            "passengers": {
                "adultCount": 1,
                "infantInLapCount": 0,
                "infantInSeatCount": 0,
                "childCount": 0,
                "seniorCount": 0
            },
            "solutions": 2,
            "refundable": false
        }
    }

    // QPX REST API URL (I censored my api key)
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=myApiKey"

    // fire request
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true,
        multipart: {
            chunked: false,
            data: [
                {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    body: requestData
                }
            ]
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
        else {

            console.log("error: " + error)
            console.log("response.statusCode: " + response.statusCode)
            console.log("response.statusText: " + response.statusText)
        }
    })
```

What I'm trying to do is passing the JSON using the multipart argument [3].
But instead of the proper JSON response I got an error (400 undefined).

When I make a request using the same JSON and API Key using CURL instead, it works fine. So there's nothing wrong with my API key or JSON.

What's wrong with my code?

**EDIT**:

working CURL example:

i) I saved the JSON which I would pass to my request into a file called "request.json":

```
{
  "request": {
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "ZRH",
        "destination": "DUS",
        "date": "2014-12-02"
      }
    ],
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1,
      "infantInLapCount": 0,
      "infantInSeatCount": 0,
      "childCount": 0,
      "seniorCount": 0
    },
    "solutions": 20,
    "refundable": false
  }
}
```

ii) then, in the terminal I switched to the directory in which the newly created request.json file was located and run (myApiKey stands for my actual API Key obviously):

```
curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=myApiKey
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/
[2] a http request client designed for nodejs: https://www.npmjs.org/package/request
[3] here is an example I found https://www.npmjs.org/package/request#multipart-related
[4] [QPX Express API is returning 400 parse error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179248/qpx-express-api-is-returning-400-parse-error)

Comment: Try removnig 'json: true' from your request

Comment: doesn't make a difference. but as far as I know this only specifies that the response is a json right?

Comment: Can you show the cURL command line that works?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using multipart?

Comment: @mscdex please see my updated original post

Comment: @cloudfeet because it's the only example I found. Maybe I'm doing it wrong

Comment: There are plenty of examples at https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
// fire request
request({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    json: requestData
}, ...
```

In this case, the `Content-type: application/json` header is automatically added.

Comment: For whatever reason, the endpoint I was hitting couldn't read the params using the first method (as if they weren't sent) but was able to do so with the second method.

Comment: Likewise to what Jamil said. I got `SyntaxError: Unexpected token &quot;<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/home/malcolm/complice/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)` with the first method.

Comment: @MalcolmOcean That's because a <br> tag is not a valid JSON content

Comment: I got this error: `[ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 23):

I worked on this for too long.  The answer that helped me was at:
[send Content-Type: application/json post with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675688/send-content-type-application-json-post-with-node-js)

Which uses the following format:

```
request({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        },
    json: requestData
//  body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
    }, function (error, resp, body) { ...
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't want multipart, but a "plain" POST request (with `Content-Type: application/json`) instead. Here is all you need:

```
var request = require('request');

var requestData = {
  request: {
    slice: [
      {
        origin: "ZRH",
        destination: "DUS",
        date: "2014-12-02"
      }
    ],
    passengers: {
      adultCount: 1,
      infantInLapCount: 0,
      infantInSeatCount: 0,
      childCount: 0,
      seniorCount: 0
    },
    solutions: 2,
    refundable: false
  }
};

request('https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=myApiKey',
        { json: true, body: requestData },
        function(err, res, body) {
  // `body` is a js object if request was successful
});
```

Comment: I tried this but got another error:

"400. That’s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know." for the full response visit http://jsfiddle.net/f71opd7p/ please

Comment: @Tobi according to the request documentation and [the code](https://github.com/request/request/blob/c522e846d2367cd20c7875a7ebf0c12bb0bec5cb/request.js#L1475-L1498), `json: true` should both `JSON.stringify()` `body` *and* `JSON.parse()` the response.

Comment: This IS the answer. Further to it you can also pipe the response `request('xxx',{ json: true, body: req.body }).pipe(res).on('error', catchErr);`

Comment: This worked for me when the accepted answer was not.

Comment: I got this error: `[ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

Now with new JavaScript version (ECMAScript 6
http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition) there is a better way to submit requests using nodejs and Promise request (http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/nstieglitz/5-great-features-in-es6-harmony)

Using library:
https://github.com/request/request-promise

```
npm install --save request
npm install --save request-promise
```

client:

```
//Sequential execution for node.js using ES6 ECMAScript
var rp = require('request-promise');

rp({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    body: {
        val1 : 1,
        val2 : 2
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
}).then(function (parsedBody) {
        console.log(parsedBody);
        // POST succeeded...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(parsedBody);
        // POST failed...
    });
```

server:

```
var express = require('express')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body);      // your JSON

    var jsonRequest = request.body;
    var jsonResponse = {};

    jsonResponse.result = jsonRequest.val1 + jsonRequest.val2;

    response.send(jsonResponse);
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 4):

Example.

```
var request = require('request');

var url = "http://localhost:3000";

var requestData = {
    ...
} 

var data = {
    url: url,
    json: true,
    body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
}

request.post(data, function(error, httpResponse, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

As inserting `json: true` option, 
sets body to JSON representation of value and adds `"Content-type": "application/json"` header. Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.
[LINK](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback)

Answer (score 2):

According to doc: 
https://github.com/request/request

The example is:

```
  multipart: {
      chunked: false,
      data: [
        {
          'content-type': 'application/json', 
          body: JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar', _attachments: {'message.txt': {follows: true, length: 18, 'content_type': 'text/plain' }}})
        },
      ]
    }
```

I think you send an object where a string is expected, replace

```
body: requestData
```

by

```
body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
       var request = require('request');
        request({
            url: "http://localhost:8001/xyz",
            json: true,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(requestData)
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel

```
var x = request.post({
       uri: config.uri,
       json: reqData
    });
```

Defining like this will be the effective way of writing your code. And application/json should be automatically added. There is no need to specifically declare it.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the json object as the body(third argument) of the fetch request.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide answers according to [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)