# POST request through a JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, post, request

I have created a server which serves the post request for a client. I am using the bodyserver, but getting some error

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
     var express = require('express');
        var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/v3/botstate/:channel/users/:userid', function (req, res) {
    console.log("hsijdaf");
    console.log(req.body);
    //console.log(req.body);        

 //  res.send('Hello POST');

})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

A client is as shown below,

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
            url: "http://localhost:8081/v3/botstate/webchat/users/siddiq",
           headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"zdoLXrB5IkwQzwV2wBoj","method":"barrister-idl","params":[]}',
            json:true
}, function(error, response, body){
console.log(error);
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  console.log(body);
});
```

while running the client getting the below error,

```
E:\TESTING>node exp.js
Example app listening at http://:::8081
SyntaxError: Unexpected token "
    at parse (E:\TESTING\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at E:\TESTING\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18
    at invokeCallback (E:\TESTING\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
    at done (E:\TESTING\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\TESTING\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You have set `Content-Type : application/json` in your client, but your `POST` data is `text/plain`, not `json`. That's why `body-parser` is failing to parse it as it was expecting `json` through `header`.

Try after removing `' '` from `body` in your client.

e.g.

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
     url: "http://localhost:8081/v3/botstate/webchat/users/siddiq",
     headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },
     body: {
       "jsonrpc":"2.0",
       "id":"zdoLXrB5IkwQzwV2wBoj",
       "method":"barrister-idl",
       "params":[]
     },
     json:true
}, function(error, response, body){
   console.log(error);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
   console.log(body);
});
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27190736/7022062  - there's a nicer version of POST'ing json without content-type explicitly defined (will use "application/json" automagically!-)