# Analog curl request with nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl, request

I should to send curl post request to remote server(nodejs) :

```
curl -X POST \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  -d '{"email":"voluumdemo@voluum.com","password":"1qaz!QAZ"}' \
  'https://api.voluum.com/auth/session'
```

I try something like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.voluum.com/auth/session',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    data: {"email":"voluumdemo@voluum.com","password":"1qaz!QAZ"}
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('Res:'+response.statusCode);
  console.log('err:'+error);
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

But its not working. I had only 400 response.

Comment: In url key in options variable you just use http instead of https try to fix it

Comment: 1 easy to spot difference is "http" vs "https"

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe i fix it, but i still get 400 response status(

Comment: @ItsMyLife i tried your curl command its working fine.. iam receiving the following response  `{
  "token" : "5rXuW8ENtpTTz3CJk8ahN7Ln59KtyKL8",
  "expirationTimestamp" : "2017-09-06T14:49:22.586Z",
  "inaugural" : false
}`

Comment: @RolandStarke Thank you so much. You save my ass)

Comment: @ItsMyLife :) here for all: [pass-json-to-http-post-request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27190736/5378743)