# how to set content type in "request" npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am sendin a request from node server to some other server , but i need to send content type

> application/json

How can i send that , I am using this format

```
request.post('https://server.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token',{form:postData},function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
    res.json({
        'error': error,
        'statusCode': response && response.statusCode,
        'body': body
    })
});
```

I am getting error  while I am trying this

```
 request.post(
        'https://server.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token',
        {
            form:postData,
            headers:{ 
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }

    },function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        res.json({
            'error': error,
            'statusCode': response && response.statusCode,
            'body': body
        })
    });
```

> "message":"Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media
>   type application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: There is some examples with content-type in the docs: https://github.com/request/request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass JSON to HTTP POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190447/pass-json-to-http-post-request)

Comment: When you provide a key json it automatically set content type application/json

Comment: @ManjeetThakur but I am getting this error "Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , and i am able to post data from postman if I set appliction/json

Comment: can you post the image of postman how you use this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Please change key name  `form` to `json`.

```
    request.post('https://server.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token', {
    json: postData
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
    res.json({
        'error': error,
        'statusCode': response && response.statusCode,
        'body': body
    })
});
```

Comment: where is header set ?

Comment: Ah , sorry I could not see that you have changed form to json and you did not mention this also , This should be accepted answer . I am changing it .

Answer (score 3):

As per [the docs](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) you need to set `json:true` for `application/json` to be added to the header

```
let data = { foo: "bar" }

request.post({
    uri: 'www.domain.com/upload',
    body: data,
    json:true
}, function (err: any, res: any, body: any) {
    //handle callback            
});
```

Answer (score -1):

See [the documentation](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers). You just need to include a value for the `headers` property in the options object:

```
request.post(
    'https://server.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token',
    {
        form: postData, /* Ensure this is a string of JSON! */
        headers:{ 
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    },
    your_callback_function
);
```

Comment: still it is sending application\/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by this ,

```
request.post({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    json: postData
},function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
    res.json({
        'error': error,
        'statusCode': response && response.statusCode,
        'body': body
    })
});
```