# Error: Argument error, options.body with node.js request library

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to print from multiple (up to two) printers using the [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
for(var i = 0; i < printers.length; i++) {
  var body = {
    "printerid": printers[i], 
    "ticket": JSON.stringify(ticket),
    "title": "TEST PRINT",
    "content": content,
    "contentType": "text/plain"
  };
  request({
    "method": "POST",
    "url": googlePrintUrl+"submit",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "OAuth " + googleAccessToken
    },
    "body": body
  }, function (error, res, body){
    if (error) {
      console.log("There was an error with Google Cloud Print");
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log("The server responded with:", body);
  }); 
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Argument error, options.body.
    at setContentLength (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:433:28)
    at Request.init (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:438:5)
    at new Request (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:127:8)
    at request (/user_code/node_modules/request/index.js:53:10)
    at printByGoogleCloud (/user_code/index.js:211:5)
    at admin.database.ref.once.then.then.then (/user_code/index.js:380:13)
```

and

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:457:11)
    at Request.write (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:1495:27)
    at end (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:545:18)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:574:7)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

This seems to be an error with the way we are using the `request` library, not with the api. But I can't figure out exactly what the error is. I've tried many different changes to the request, but none have worked. Thankful for help.

Answer (score 3):

For your actual post data, try using JSON.stringify.

```
"body" : JSON.stringify(body)
```

See: [Request JSON Payload](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1717)

Or you can pass json instead of the body.

```
json: body
```

See: [JSON HTTP POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190447/pass-json-to-http-post-request)

Comment: should be marked as answer, at least it solved my problem. Thank you, very much