# Web API Fetch Request body is undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, webapi

I was going through the docs of the Request interface in Fetch API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

The example where we set the body does not seem to work. Tried on chrome dev console (version 84.0.4147.89) and also on firefox (84.0).

```
const request = new Request('https://example.com', {method: 'POST', body: '{"foo": "bar"}'});
console.log(request.url);
console.log(request.method);
console.log(request.body);
```

This results in,

```
https://example.com/
POST
undefined
```

**What am I doing wrong here...?**

#### EDIT:

The following is working,

```
request.json().then((j)=>{console.log(j)});
```

This leads me to believe that the body was set, but the getter is not working for some reason.

Can anyone shed light on what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190447/pass-json-to-http-post-request

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example:

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        foo: 'bar'
    })
}
const response = await fetch('https://example.com', requestOptions)
const result = await response.json();
```

Comment: This works, I'm able to make requests using `fetch(url, options)`, and is in fact what I ended up doing.
But I was specifically wondering why the Request.body was not working as expected.

Comment: `body` cannot accept `object` as value, so we need to convert `object` to `string` by `JSON.stringify()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch